# What is the best way to convert this date format "2019-11-07T13:30:00+05:30" to utc date?

Tags: c#

I need a way to convert this date: 
2019-11-07T13:30:00+05:30
to utc.

While also taking into account that it has +05:30

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

```
string dateEnd = "2019-11-07T13:30:00+05:30";
DateTime converted = Convert.ToDateTime(dateEnd);
```

It converts it to this date:

> 29-Aug-19 9:00:00 AM

Comment: use DateTime.ParseExact

Comment: I see no way how this string with month/day value of `11-07` would be converted to have the month/day value of `08-29` (august 29). Is this the actual input and the actual output?

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for ToUniversalTime?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Try out what DateTime.Parse() does with it. If it eats it, the it is ToUniversalTime(). Parse and ToString have all the timezone knowledge that Windows has. So we do not need to deal with those madening timezones: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dateEnd="2019-11-07T13:30:00+05:30";
    matchObject.DateEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(dateEnd).ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: @Abra `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` does return a `DateTime` object, you are right the code is not copy-paste bullet proof, but the answer has information enought to be useful and OP marked it as useful

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as a warning ahead: Dealing with timezones can be [madening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY). I try to avoid it whever I can. Luckily in .NET, we can for most cases.

Internally DateTime stores the amount of [Ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks) since the start of the Unix Epoch (1/1/1970). Any string and any other property you see? Those are just a interpretation of that one value.

The ToString() and Parse() functions are really good at their job. If not given another culture, they will retreive the current Culture set for windows (or their Thread). For DateTimes it will also get your local timezones to factor into the display (as nessesary).

Now the debugger is just a programm too. And it will of course display the average DateTime it is viewd from *your Windows current Timezone*. Or rather the timezones used by the user this programm runs in - wich can be a temporary/compilation only user with all kinds of oddities.

With the Input string the timezone of Origin is clearly noted. I can not remember having seen that Syntax, but it is propably like providing a specific port for a WebRequest. No guessing or implying of values involved. And it is accepted by Parse, so whatever :)

If you get a DateFrom a UTC related function, it will set the [Kind property to UTC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind). Wich should fix the whole "Display in Local Timezone" thing.